# What's the benefit for using a Kalman filter for training a neural network compared to other optimization algorithms?

Tags: neural-networks, training, kalman-filter

I found a [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.80.1421&rep=rep1&type=pdf) about using an Unscented Kalman Filter(UKF) for traning a neural network.

The UKF filter is modified so it works for parameter estimation. Assume that we have a neural network model $\hat d_k = G(x_k, W_k)$ where $G$ is the neural network, $x_k$ is the input **vector**, $W_k$ is the parameter gain **matrix** and $\hat d_k$ is the output **vector**.

This paper counts servral methods to train a neural network.

- Gradient descent
- Quasi-Newton
- UKF parameter estimation

**So my questions for you are:**

1. What's the benefit for using a kalman filter for training a neural network compared to other optimization algorithms?
2. I remember that I have been using gradient descent methods and they work, but I have always used regularization. Is that due to the noise in the data?
3. If I'm using a UKF-filter as parameter estimation, I can avoid regularization then?
4. Is this UKF parameter estimation algorithm only made for 1 layer neural network, or can it be used for deep neural networks as well?

Comment: Hello, asking multiple questions in a single post is not recommended. Please try to split the questions into multiple posts.

Comment: @hanugm Yes! I created a new question with only 1 question. https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/31701/using-parameter-estimation-for-training-a-neural-network